# Capturing the dragged element and the replaced elements with SortableJS

Tags: javascript, django, sortablejs

How can I grab the dragged and the replaced elements when using Sortable JS ?

The JS:

```
var originalList;
var sortable = Sortable.create(selection, {
  handle: '.bars-move',
  animation: 150,

/// not sure what to write here 

});
```

the table:

```
<table>
  <tbody id="selection">
  {{ formset.management_form }}
  {% for form in formset %}
    {{form.id}}
    <tr id="{{form.instance.id}}">
      <td>
          <img src="{% static 'img/bars_icon.svg' %}" class="bars-move">
      </td>
      <td>{{form.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var originalArray;
var sortable = Sortable.create(selection, {
  handle: '.bars-move',
  animation: 150,

  onStart: function (evt) {
    originalArray = sortable.toArray();
  },

  onEnd: function(evt) {
    var dragged_id = originalArray[evt.oldIndex];
    var replaced_id = originalArray[evt.newIndex];
  },

});
```